# Cannot resolve 'query(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],null, null, null, null)'

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio

I am trying to create a film database in an Android application, but it is returning with error. Any ideas what this means?

```
public Cursor returnData()
{
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {FILM, ACTOR, ACTOR2, DIRECTOR, DESCRIPTION}, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: @Blackbelt It's the name of my SQLite Database. Should I put more code in this question?

Comment: @NicolaBA: add one more parameter to `query` method current you are passing six parameters

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK How do I do this?

Comment: @NicolaBA: Use `return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {FILM, ACTOR, ACTOR2, DIRECTOR, DESCRIPTION}, null, null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 1):

Need to add an extra 'null' value.

```
 public Cursor returnData()
{
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {FILM, ACTOR, ACTOR2, DIRECTOR, DESCRIPTION}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```